# Узнать количество знаков после запятой

Tags: c#, .net

Для того, что бы узнать количество знаков после запятой можно использовать:

```
 var count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(value)[3])[2];
```

А как это работает? Почему в `decimal.GetBits(value)` берем третий элемент массива, а в `BitConverter.GetBytes` второй?

Comment: В decimal старшие 32 бита (из 128) хранят знак и экспоненту. Из них биты с 16 по 23 как раз экспонента и есть ([ссылка](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Decimal)). Можно на примере какого-то числа рассмотреть.

Comment: Спасибо! А в результате BitConverter.GetBytes почему [2]?

Comment: @Pavel "старшие 32 бита из 128" - это последний элемент массива (3), "биты с 16 по 23" - третий байт (2).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял!